# How can I see what arguments vim was invoked with?

Tags: argument-list

Is it possible to see what arguments vim was invoked with when it was run?

```
vim -O foo bar
```

To show `-O foo bar`, but especially if there are configurations set like `-Z`?

Comment: According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10357374) your best bet might be to get the command used to start Vim at the OS level and to parse this data. I don't remember the feature being implemented natively since 2012 when the answer were written but maybe that changed.

Comment: I confess I’m almost surprised vim doesn’t expose a readonly `v:flags` or `v:argv` or something like that

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. On Unix like operating systems, you might get around by parsing `/proc/*/cmdline`, e.g. `:sp /proc/'.getpid().'/cmdline'`